# RollupJS generate only index.js

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I'm having some trouble with **RollupJS**.

I have one component library using **typescript**, **react**, **AntDesign** which using rollup.

Here my rollup config:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url';
import postcssModules from 'postcss-modules';
import pkg from './package.json';

const cssExportMap = {};

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  external: [
    {
      'react': 'react',
      'react-dom': 'react-dom'
    },
    // Make antd library styles to be external to current project
    /^antd[.]*/,
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    url(),
    typescript({
      exclude: ['*.d.ts', '**/*.d.ts', '**/*.stories.tsx', '**/*.spec.tsx'],
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      clean: true,
    }),
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      plugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }]],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [
        postcssModules({
          getJSON (id, exportTokens) {
            cssExportMap[id] = exportTokens;
          }
        })
      ],
      getExportNamed: false,
      getExport (id) {
        return cssExportMap[id];
      },
      extract: 'build/styles.css',
      use: ['sass', ['less', { javascriptEnabled: true, modifyVars: {
        'hack': `true; @import "./public/theme/variables.module.less"`
      }}]]
    })
  ],
};
```

and my package.json has some scripts:

```
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "prepare": "yarn run build"
```

in local everything works fine and all the files are generated.

But when I'm using my library in a create-react-app application as dependency.

```
"ui-kit": "git+https://****:x-oauth-basic@github.com/****/ui_kit_fe.git"
```

rollup generate only index.js inside build folder,

it should be:
 - style.css
 - index.es.js
 - index.js.map

but they are not there...

Comment: Hi did you find solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem myself. My build folder was present in the `.gitignore` file, hence all its content except the `main` entry point was excluded from installation . I've fixed this by adding the build folder into the `files` array in `package.json`:

```
"files": ["build/**/*"],
"main": "build/index.js",
```

You can find more info here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#files